# How to handle a cancelled OpenId authentication, denied permissions

Tags: spring-security

When a user is redirected to Google to login, but then clicks 'Cancel' when granting permissions, I get the following error in my OpenIDAuthenticationFilter:

> "No claimed identity supplied in authentication request"

and in my handler:

> OpenIDAuthenticationFailureHandler org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Unable to process claimed identity ''

How can I properly catch this, knowing that the user denied requested permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In fact , I fixed the problem,

first detect Referer:

```
if (request.getHeader("Referer") != null 
&& request.getHeader("Referer").startsWith(myOpenIdServerURL)) {
```

if it is in, it means openId server reject your request, then redirect to login page with error code:

```
...
redirectUrl = redirectUrl + "?error=access_denied";
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectUrl, model);
```